# Is it possible to replace &amp; with & in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I tried to do that with `replace($val, 'amp;', '')`, but seems like `&amp;` is atomic entity to the parser. Any other ideas?

I need it to get rid of double escaping, so I have constructions like `&amp;#8112;` in input file.

UPD:
Also one important notice: I have to make this substitution only inside of specific tags, not inside of every tag.

Comment: What is the result format, also XML, or HTML, or plain text? As you seem to have `replace` you use at least an XSLT 2 processor so check whether character maps help https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#character-maps

Comment: end result is *.html file with `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace, but I am forced to use XML output method for other reasons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you serialize there is always (if supported) the disable-output-escaping hack, see http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/nbUY4kh which transforms

```
<root>
    <foo>a &amp; b</foo>
    <bar>a &amp; b</bar>
</root>
```

selectively into

```
<root>
    <foo>a & b</foo>
    <bar>a &amp; b</bar>
</root>
```

by using `<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` in the template matching `foo/text()`:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foo/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

To achieve the same selective replacement with a character map you could replace the ampersand in `foo` `text()` children (or descendants if necessary) with a character not used elsewhere in your document and then use the map to map it to an unescaped ampersand:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output use-character-maps="doe"/>

    <xsl:character-map name="doe">
        <xsl:output-character character="«" string="&amp;"/>
    </xsl:character-map>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foo/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&amp;', '«')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

That way

```
<root>
    <foo>a &amp; b</foo>
    <bar>a &amp; b</bar>
</root>
```

is also transformed to

```
<root>
    <foo>a & b</foo>
    <bar>a &amp; b</bar>
</root>
```

see http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/pPgCcoj for a sample.

Answer (score 2):

If your XML contains &#8112; and you believe that this is a double-escaped representation of the character with codepoint 8112, then you can convert it to this character using the XPath expression

```
codepoints-to-string(xs:integer(replace($input, '&#([0-9]+);', $1)))
```

remembering that if you write this XPath expression in XSLT, then the `&` must be written as `&amp;`.